# Only load Property Database or Cancel Model load after querying Property Database

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

With our application, we're loading large models into the viewer and experience issues on mobile devices. We've decided to create views that break up our model and then load the correct viewable when needed. We need to query the overall model at least one time though, and we're running into issues.

One issue is that I would like to *not* load the geometry, and only load the property database, with the ability to use `getBulkProperties` and other `model` methods.

**Is there an option to only load the property database?**

The opposite of: `const options = { skipPropertyDb: true}`

If that is not possible, there is another solution, but I have one issue. The workflow goes:

1. Load the model
2. Wait for the object tree
3. Query the properties we need
4. Cancel the model load

The property query results relatively quickly as I don't need to wait for all of the geometry to load. The issue is that the Viewer does not stop the load, and I get a lot of `Cannot read property 'findMaterial' of null` (from `SvfLoader.js`) when I try to cancel the loading with `viewer.tearDown(); viewer.finish();`. I've also tried `viewer.impl.cancelLoad(e)` but that didn't have any effect.

**How would we correctly cancel the in-progress loading of a model?**

Lastly, using model derivative to query the model from the server is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewer isn't exactly cut out for that purpose (data navigation) so I'd recommend to download the property database and create your own UI - see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/working-viewer-data-serverlessly-thumbnails-screesnshots-and-serverless-upload) for details.

But if you insist perhaps just try something similar to `skipProperty` and just load only a single node (of geometry) - see a live demo [here](https://jsbin.com/wuquhus/edit?js)

Comment: I went the route of passing a single node into the viewer and that worked.